# Build a Docker with Flask application and Solr

Tags: docker, flask, solr, solrcloud

I'm new to Docker, I need to "dockerize" my Flask app that use a Solr server in background (in solrcloud mode).
I understood how to deploy my app on Docker, but without Solr server.
I don't know if it should be done in only 1 dockerfile, use docker-compose or use multi-stage docker.

At the moment I tried with something like this:

```
### Multi-stage build
FROM solr:8.8.0

ADD custom-config /opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/custom-config
ADD solr.in.sh /etc/default
ADD *.jar /opt/solr/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/

EXPOSE 8983

### II image
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

ADD . /flask-test

WORKDIR /flask-test

RUN apt update -y &&  apt upgrade -y && pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY --from=0 /opt/solr .

CMD ["solr", "start -c"]
CMD ["solr", "create_collection", "-c test", "-d /opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/custom-config"]
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Obviously that doesn't work.
Have you got any suggestion? thanks

**Updates**

After some suggestions I've separate in two distinct Dockerfile the two original stages and trying to combine them in a docker-compose.yml.
Thus, I had a Dockerfile for the Flask app:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
ADD . /flask-test
WORKDIR /flask-test
RUN apt update -y &&  apt upgrade -y && pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

And a Dockerfile for Solr server:

```
FROM solr:8.8.0
ADD custom-config /opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/custom-config
ADD solr.in.sh /etc/default
ADD *.jar /opt/solr/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/
EXPOSE 8983
CMD solr start -c && solr create_collection -c test-d /opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/custom-config
```

In the final step I did this docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
 flask:
  build: .
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"
 solr:
  build: ./docker-solr
  restart: unless-stopped
  environment:
   - Dsolr.default.confdir=/opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/custom-config/conf
  ports:
   - "8983:8983"
```

When running the *docker-compose up*, all works fine and my Flask application is starting, but the problem is that the Solr service continue to fires up the command and reboots, thus, my Flask app that lean on localhost:8983 cannot work properly.

Any help?

Comment: Especially if the Solr process has a network-accessible server component, best practice is almost always to run the two processes in two separate containers.

Comment: At the moment it runs locally

Comment: Separate containers and docker-compose or something similar is the way if you want to keep everything as simple, coordinated deployment

Comment: Thanks guys, I updated the question as I'm trying to accomplish this task using docker-compose

Answer (score 1):

As you indicate in your Dockerfile  you are using multiple stages on the same dockerfile (number of stages calculated by the number of FROM instruction).

The latest FROM will eliminate the other FORM so we only using multiple from to reduce image size and pass data from stage to other and it's not the case for you.

What you need is to separate the two part on two separate containers using two dockerfile and after docker-compose.yml file,

I hope that this help you to fix your issue .